# How to merge a router have variable with variables in array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a config route :

```js
const routers = {
  home: '/',
  category: '/category/:slug',
}
```

and an array :

```js
array = [
  { id: 1, slug: 'table'},
  { id: 2, slug: 'chair'},
]
```

I use `array.map()` to generate a list of `NavLink` components:

```
array.map(item => {
  return <NavLink key={item.id} to={routers.category+item.slug}>
    {item.slug}
  </NavLink>
})
```

But it doesn't work. The result is `localhost:3000/category/:slugtable` and `localhost:3000/category/:slugchair`.

The expected result is `localhost:3000/category/table`.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that for the link target you are using string concatenation.

```
to={routers.category+item.slug}
```

This results in link targets like `"/category/:slug" + "chair"` which results in string literals `"/category/:slugchair"` which likely isn't what you expected or have a route path to match.

`react-router` exports a path generating utility, oddly enough, named [`generatePath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/generate-path).

> `generatePath` interpolates a set of params into a route path string
> with `:id` and `*` placeholders. This can be useful when you want to
> eliminate placeholders from a route path so it matches statically
> instead of using a dynamic parameter.
>
> ```
> generatePath("/users/:id", { id: "42" }); // "/users/42"
> generatePath("/files/:type/*", {
>   type: "img",
>   "*": "cat.jpg",
> }); // "/files/img/cat.jpg"
> ```

Use `generatePath` to take the `"/category/:slug"` path and the `slug` param to generate the target path.

```js
import { NavLink, generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

...

array.map(item => (
  <NavLink key={item.id} to={generatePath(routers.category, item)}>
    {item.slug}
  </NavLink>
))
```

The `slug` property on `item` will be assigned to the `":slug"` route path param.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hard coded string, the slug will not be replaced.
you can use backticks.

```
to={routers.category+`${item.slug}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you change your routes object structure your problem is solved. You can separate pathnames from routes.

For example:

```js
const HOME_PATH = '/'
const CATEGORY_PATH = '/category'
```

Then your routes object something like the below:

```js
const routes = {
    home: HOME_PATH,
    category: `${CATEGORY_PATH}/:slug`,
}
```

Then you can solve your problem:

```js
array.map((item) => {
    return (
        <NavLink
            key={item.id}
            to={CATEGORY_PATH + '/' + item.slug}>
            {item.slug}
        </NavLink>
    )
})
```